# How do I validate by file extension in filepond?

Tags: filepond

Filepond respects the 'accept' attribute on file inputs.  It sounds like the 'accept' attribute by default in browsers supports:

1. file extensions
2. mime types
3. the three generic audio, video and image wildcard mimetypes (`audio/*`, `video/*`, `image/*`)

However the [file-validate-type plugin](https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/api/plugins/file-validate-type/) validates by mime-type, which is not very reliable.

Is it possible to configure filepond to validate by file extension?

We tried using the `fileValidateTypeDetectType` option to map from file-extension to a mime-type that is in the list, but that was pretty hacky and unmaintainable.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like by default, that plugin resolves using the mime-type the browser decides, and `fileValidateTypeDetectType` does allow you to override the mime-type that the browser decides.

However, you can also pass an extension to the `resolve` callback, and it works as long as the extension is in the list!

```
const filePond = FilePond.create(inputElement, {
    allowFileTypeValidation: true,
    fileValidateTypeDetectType: (source, _type) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, _reject) => {
        const extension = `.${source.name.split(".").pop()}`;
        resolve(extension);
      })
    },
    ...
```